# UK visit visa company sponsor support documents

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, pakistan

I am applying for a visit visa to the UK to attend a competition, I have an invitation letter for it. A company is willing to sponsor me, but I need info on what documents are needed.

I have an idea of docs needed if its a person:
1. bank statement of last 6 months
2. letter from bank manager
3. Signed affidavit

I need an idea of what is needed for a company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirements are largely the same.

Invitation from the competition organiser, and other documents that you mentioned. Letter from your employer confirming you have agreed absence from work.

The point being to show that you can pay for your costs and have, maybe more importantly, good reason (job, family responsibilities, etc) to leave the UK before your visa expires. So anything else you want to present to support that.